# Can the order of values be determined in the reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Suppose I want to do some research of the annual sales trending of products. In the raw input I have all products sorted by years line by line like this: `product-id sales-volume year`. In the mapper I would produce `<product-id, sales-volume>` pairs so then in the Reducer I could get all sales data of the same product. The question is: is it guaranteed that the order of values in the Reducer be the same with the raw input？If not, how can I do that?

Comment: Reducer value order is not guaranteed. Use a higher level tool like Hive, Pig, or Spark to order the values

Comment: Look at secondary sort.